# VB.Net - Retrieve Image from Database Column and then attach as an attachment to an email

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I have an application that i am supporting. I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve an image from a database (Image Datatype) and then attach this image to an email. The application currently embeds the images to an email but i need it to attach images instead.

I have read in to adding attachments to emails but it is grabbing the image froma  file location, rather than a database field. I haven't not come across anything that matches my needs.

Do i need to somehow save the image locally then send the email using the saved image?

SQL Server 2014

**Pre Existing Get Image Function**

```
     Private Function GetImage() As Byte()
            Dim rdrImage As SqlDataReader
            Dim strSQL As String
            Dim arrContent As Byte()
            strSQL = "SELECT Photo FROM " & CommonThings1.GetDatabaseSuffix & "Images "
            strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE PhotoID = " & Request("ZQ") & " AND Random = " & Request("WXP")
            cmCM.CommandText = strSQL
            rdrImage = cmCM.ExecuteReader
            rdrImage.Read()
            arrContent = CType(rdrImage("Photo"), Byte())
            rdrImage.Close()
            Return arrContent
        End Function
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using? Can you show us **some code** to get started?

Comment: The MSDN documentation for the `MailMessage` class contains a code example that includes adding an attachment. It's available in C# but not VB but it's fairly easy to see what's going on. In that example, it uses the `Attachment` constructor that takes a `String` containing a file path as an argument. You can use the one that takes a `Stream` instead. [Click here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469562-Saving-Images-in-Databases) to see an example of how to get a `MemoryStream` containing image data from a database.

Comment: @marc_s see updated question. Thanks

Comment: The `image` data type is **deprecated** and will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s Yeah i have read about this. In terms of this is the one and only application i use with this datatype. Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should go something like this, writing this off the top of my head so not tested ...

```
Dim stream as new MemoryStream(GetImage())
stream.Position = 0 'If I remember correctly, need to be at beginning of stream to read from first position when attaching
Dim MSG As New MailMessage
Dim ToAddress = New MailAddress(SomeEmailAddress)
Dim FromAddress As New MailAddress("SomeEmail@AnEmail.com")
Try
    With MSG
        .To.Add(ToAddress)
        .From = FromAddress
        .Subject = "Your Photo"
        .IsBodyHtml = True
        .Body = SomeHTML 
        .Attachments.Add(New Attachment(stream , "Photo.jpg", "application/jpg"))
    End With
Dim SendMessage As New SmtpClient("smtp.MyMailServer.com")
SendMessage.Send(MSG)
```

Comment: This worked! Now that there can be multiple images per record. I need to do this for each image. Thank you for your help.